# mvvm-light unable to create WP7 app "the project type is not supported by this installation"

Tags: mvvm-light

I have been trying to learn MVVM using Laurent Bugnion MVVM light method.
I have installed binaries and templates (using latest version dated 23 Jan 2011)
I can create WPF and SL4 projects but when I try to create a WP7 project VS2010 throws an error.
"The project file c:\users\tonby\AppData\Local\temp\ime44m4x.2hg\Temp\MvvmLigh5.csproj cannot be opened.
The project type is not supported by this installation.

I have checked the template files are not blocked so unsure what to try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install the Windows Phone 7 tools?

Comment: Brilliant! Thought I had duh. Works now.